# Mondrian MDX - Filter Not Applying to Multiple Members Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

We currently have a query that shows the value of total quantity, or sales across store locations and departments, I intersect the quantity sold aggregated measure against locations, and the results are fine.

When we try to filter by total qty > 500, I am only seeing the sum of quantity evaluated by the location's value, not grouped by location and department.

HAVING is not seemingly supported, and if I include a where filter at the bottom, there is an issue with the same family/members being used multiple times and it's not allowed.

```
SELECT 
  {HEAD([dim_productfamily.hier_productfamily].[lvl_department].Members, 5)}
ON ROWS,
  FILTER
  (
    {HEAD([dim_locations.hier_locations].[lvl_location].Members, 5) * [Measures].[total_qty]},
    [Measures].[total_qty] > 500
  )
ON COLUMNS
FROM 
  [sales_daily] 
WHERE 
  {[dim_date.hier_date].[lvl_date].[20170521] : [dim_date.hier_date].[lvl_date].[20170730] }
```

The above query returns fine, but I get values that I've tested only really compare against the location sum(total_qty).

**EDIT for Different Grouping**

I tried using the below query, which seems to work. I think the way we render a table is improper in this case, as the output does seem to work fine.

```
SELECT 
  FILTER
  (
     {HEAD([dim_productfamily.hier_productfamily].[lvl_department].Members, 5) * HEAD([dim_locations.hier_locations].[lvl_location].Members, 5)},
     [Measures].[total_qty] > 26
  )
ON ROWS,
  [Measures].[total_qty]
ON COLUMNS
FROM 
   [sales_daily] 
WHERE 
  {[dim_date.hier_date].[lvl_date].[20170521] : [dim_date.hier_date].[lvl_date].[20170730] }
```

Is this what you were thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your filter you really have not grouped by location and department. You have only grouped by location. An easy fix is the you bring both location and product on the same axis and that the measure on the oposite axis. Then filter it. It would work.

Comment: Please see my revised answer, with the second sample (I think it's what you were looking for)

Comment: Yup, that is it. So can have my suggestion marked as answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem again, you can query it in the below manner. This will let you use the orignal grouping.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Data Type3] AS ([Geography].[Country].CurrentMember,[Product].[Product].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])

SELECT 
FILTER
(
{[Product].[Product].Members}
,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] > 2000
)
ON rows,
FILTER
(
([Geography].[Country].members, {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
,[Measures].[Data Type3]}),
[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] > 2000
)
ON columns
FROM 
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Mondrian doesn't allow measures to be used in more than one axis (members either).

Comment: We are not actually using measure on more than one axis. the measure are just on columns. We are filtering it. I tried the above query on SSAS, try it in mondrian and kindly do let me know.

Comment: That query doesn't work with our information. It is on Mondrian, and doesn't work the same as SSAS. We get this error: No function matches signature '(<set>, <set>)'